# What is the rule of mutable referencing inner values from mutable references?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

What is the rule of mutable referencing inner values from mutable references?

This works:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Outer {
    name: String,
    inner: Inner,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Inner {
    val: String,
}

fn main() {
    let mut test = Outer {
        inner: Inner {
            val: String::from("test"),
        },
        name: String::from("name"),
    };
    let outer = &mut test;
    let inner = &mut outer.inner;
    *inner = Inner {
        val: String::from("x"),
    };
    outer.inner.val.push('b');
    println!("{:?}", outer); // Outer { name: "name", inner: Inner { val: "xb" } }
}
```

This fails:

```
fn main() {
    let mut test = Outer {
        inner: Inner {
            val: String::from("test"),
        },
        name: String::from("name"),
    };
    let outer = &mut test;
    let inner = &mut test.inner; // note this time I'm using test instead of outer
    *inner = Inner {
        val: String::from("x"),
    };
    outer.inner.val.push('b');
    println!("{:?}", outer);
}
```

with:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `test.inner` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:20:17
   |
19 |     let outer = &mut test;
   |                 --------- first mutable borrow occurs here
20 |     let inner = &mut test.inner; // note this time I'm using test instead of outer
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
...
24 |     outer.inner.val.push('b');
   |     --------------- first borrow later used here
```

Comment: In general you either use `test.inner = Inner{...}` without creating a new borrow, or you release an old borrow before creating the new one `{ let outer = &mut test; ...; /*outer is destroyed*/ } { let inner =  &mut test.inner; ... }`

Comment: You can use an existing reference to refer into a value further inside it - that doesn't count as aliasing. However it will render the outer reference unusable while the inner reference is live. For example, if you swap the `*inner = ...` and `outer.inner.val.push` lines in the first example, it will stop compiling. In summary, you can't have aliasing, but you can have _nesting_ (of sorts) of mutable references.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is explained in the [Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html#mutable-references).

The rules for mutability are (written from my memory):

- You can modify a variable's content if it owns its content, and is not borrowed
- A variable can have only one mutable reference at a time, and only the mutable reference is able to read or edit the variable's content

Your first code compiles because `inner` borrows `outer`, which is not borrowed yet, making `outer` unusable during `inner`'s lifetime.

In the second code however, you borrow twice the same variable, breaking the third rule I've written